# JNLP downloading multiple times

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I am developing a web start application. I am just exploring now and a small POC i developed works well barring one problem. A fresh download of the jnlp file is triggered every time the application is launched. I am serving the app from a local installation of tomcat. Also i haven't signed the app. Could any of these two reasons be a possible cause behind the multiple downloads?

Comment: Why do you use Java Webstart when it is a local installation?

Comment: @JMax The local installation is that of tomcat. I am using tomcat for local development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with multiple downloads was that it looked bad in terms of user experience. This can be overcome by using jnlp:// instead of http:// .

Previously : http ://address_of_my_jnlp_file/fileName.jnlp

Now : jnlp://address_of_my_jnlp_file/fileName.jnlp

The browser automatically detects that the download is a WebStart application and delegates it to the local JRE which downloads and runs it directly without triggering a browser download.